# Display logged in user asp.net

Tags: asp.net, authentication

I have made a little custom log-in page in asp.net, see code:

```
        Dim strCon As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("Goed").ConnectionString


        'Create Connection String And SQL Statement
        Dim strSelect As String = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_LogIn WHERE Gebruiker = @Gebruiker AND Wachtwoord = @Wachtwoord"

        Dim con As New SqlConnection(strCon)
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand()
        cmd.Connection = con
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        cmd.CommandText = strSelect

        Dim Gebruiker As New SqlParameter("@Gebruiker", _
                                          SqlDbType.VarChar)
        Gebruiker.Value = TxtUs.Text.Trim().ToString()
        cmd.Parameters.Add(Gebruiker)

        Dim Wachtwoord As New SqlParameter("@Wachtwoord", _
                                           SqlDbType.VarChar)
        Wachtwoord.Value = TxtPw.Text.Trim().ToString()
        cmd.Parameters.Add(Wachtwoord)


        con.Open()
        Dim result As Integer = DirectCast(cmd.ExecuteScalar(), Int32)
        con.Close()

        If result >= 1 Then
            Response.Redirect("default.aspx")
        Else
            lblMsg.Text = "Gebruikers naam en of wachtwoord kloppen niet"
        End If

    End Sub
```

As you can see it directs to Default.aspx.

On my defaults.aspx page I have a header. In this header I want a small label to sdhow the logged in user something like: Hello [User] How can this be done?

Comment: I advice you to use asp.net membership instead of doing it from scratch. then you can use the loginname control to show the logged in user name, check this link:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178329(v=vs.100).aspx#the_loginname_control

Comment: Just another note, I think you might know it, but always separate your data layer from your presentation layer. That is don't put code that directly speaks with you database, in your aspx page.

Comment: yes @HassanMokdad is right, business layer, DAL and presentation layer must be seperated. Still as we try and learn more and more daily we get use to these common practices

Comment: @Hassan Mokdad not sure what you mean to be honest

Comment: http://www.beansoftware.com/ASP.NET-Tutorials/Three-Tier-Architecture.aspx will help you to understand the Three Tier Architecture in ASP.NET thats what Hassan was pointing to

Comment: ahh oke thanks, I am learnign asp for my internship. Seems like i have a long way to go

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Using Sessions:**

While Directing to new page (at Login.aspx-in button's onClick event)

```
Session["valueName"]=value;
```

On new page( default.aspx in your case) use:

```
Label1.Text=Session["valueName"].ToString();
```

**Or you can use cookies as well:**

**CREATE:**

```
Response.Cookies("userInfo")("userName") = "DiederikEEn"
Response.Cookies("userInfo")("lastVisit") = DateTime.Now.ToString()
Response.Cookies("userInfo").Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1)
```

**READING:**

```
If Not Request.Cookies("userName") Is Nothing Then
    Label1.Text = Server.HtmlEncode(Request.Cookies("userName").Value)
End If

If Not Request.Cookies("userName") Is Nothing Then
    Dim aCookie As HttpCookie = Request.Cookies("userName")
    Label1.Text = Server.HtmlEncode(aCookie.Value)
End If
```

More here:

1. [Cookies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178194%28v=vs.100%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1)
2. [Sessions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87069683%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: Do I have to put that in the `IF` ?

Comment: all have to implanted in login.aspx?

Comment: In short, when you are creating a session or writing a cookie it must be in your login.aspx (in onClick event of the redirect button) and when you want to read the same cookie and session it must be at your Default.aspx Page_Load event...well if you are using session: *Session["valueName"]=value;* must be in your login page in a onClick event and *Label1.Text=Session["valueName"].ToString();* must be at your Default.aspx page..also edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you can create header in your master page then you can add  `Hello [User]`  there and call the session.